# What is the backstory for these two men in The Hobbit?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, character-identification, desolation-of-smaug

These two people give Thorin the staredown when he arrives at the Prancing Pony in Bree.

> [image: Baldy] [image: Weirdo]

Who are these people? I didn't recall reading about them in the books.

Answer (score 14):

In a word: **Jackson-verse**.

These Men aren't mentioned at all in *The Hobbit* book. They were just made-up for Peter Jackson's Hobbit movies.

#### [For the first guy:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5U18.jpg)

- Alleged name: "Bill Ferny Senior"
- Actor: Dallas Barnett

  > Dallas Barnett was born on February 29, 1964 in Rochester, New York, USA. He is an actor and producer, known for The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug (2013), [...].
  >
  > <sub>[IMDb Dallas Barnett](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2069512/)</sub>
  >
  > Bill Ferny Sr. was a Man of Bree and father of Bill Ferny who worked as an assassin, mercenary and bandit, alongside his partner in crime, the Squint.
  >
  > <sup>[Lord of the Rings Wikia](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Bill_Ferny_Sr.)</sup>
- Alleged relation(s): Bill Ferny, son

#### [For the second guy:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naWdi.jpg)

- Alleged name: "The Squint"
- Actor: Matt Smith

  > Matt grew up on the stories of Tolkien and George Lucas, and his role as Squint in 'The Desolation of Smaug' is his first major movie appearance.
  >
  > <sub>[IMDb Matt Smith](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm6131513/)</sub>
  >
  > The Squint was a Man of Bree and father of the Squint-eyed Southerner who worked as an assassin, mercenary and bandit along with his partner in crime Bill Ferny Sr.
  >
  > <sub>[Lord of the Rings Wikia](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Squint)</sub>
- Alleged relation(s): [The squint-eyed southerner](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159381/who-exactly-was-the-squint-eyed-southerner-in-the-lord-of-the-rings/159382#159382), son

---

#### In the books

Bill Ferny's and the southerner's fathers aren't mentioned at all in the books, therefore there is **no backstory for them based on canon sources**.

Comment: I've heard theres a quote going round on the site about jackson-verse, seems like it would suit here :P